# MySql - How to diagnose why connections are being refused?

Tags: .net, mysql

I'm working on getting an application deployed to our live server, that uses Connector/Net 6.4.4 to connect our .NET application to MySql and am getting the following exception thrown:

> Reading from the stream has failed. Inner Exception: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

Research so far suggests that MySql is blocking the connection. We're relatively new to MySql, so not that aware of the diagnostic tools available.

How can I diagnose the specific reason for the failed connection?

**Update:**

Dmitry Scriptin - The test result set is tiny, I've set up specific test queries that do the bare minimum.
josnidhin - The error log out puts nothing at all.
Alex Lynch - The connection is local.

Are there any other logs that are kept that might be outside of standard error log?

P.S. This is mysql v 5.1.11

Comment: How big is you resultset? try reducing the resultset size. if it works with smaller resultsets then it might be a mysql variable config issue. Could you also add the complete stack trace

Comment: One thing to potentially consider: Mysql with default settings (in my experience) will only accept connections from localhost. if you're trying to connect from a remote machine and haven't configured mysql correctly, it won't allow you to connect. Also, mysql users (in the `mysql`.`users` table) have a "host" column that decides whether or not an address can connect. Once again, this usually only allows local users to connect. If this is the case, changing the appropriate mysql users "host" column to a wildcard (%) may fix your problem (but is not good for security!) Good luck.

Comment: Have updated post in reply to comments...

Comment: Reading past the end of stream has nothing to do with 'connections being refused'. If connections were 'being refused' there would be no 'stream' to 'read past the end of'.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with MySQL 5.6.5, the table performance_schema.host_cache shows why a connection fails, with details about each possible root causes.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/host-cache-table.html

Comment: Sorry, this is MySql 5.1.11. I should have mentioned in OP